# .NETでBootstrapのModalがOnClickイベント後に閉じてしまう。

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

ASP.NET C#にてWebアプリケーションを作成しています。

BootStrapのModalを使用しています。
モーダル表示用のボタンクリック時に
サーバ側処理でOnclickイベントを入れているのですが、
このイベント発生直後にモーダルが勝手に閉じてしまいます。

sample.aspx：modal表示ボタン

```
<input type="button" id="BtnShowModal" name="BtnShowModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-BtnShowModal" value="モーダル表示" onserverclick="BtnShowModal_Click" runat="server" />
```

sample.aspx：モーダル本体

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-BtnShowModal" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-label">タイトル</h4>
        </div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px;">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>                       
                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">閉じる</button>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" Text="保存" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample.aspx.cs：ボタンクリックイベント

```
protected void BtnShowModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onserverclick`なのでポストバックが発生し、ページ全体または`UpdatePanel`が再読み込みされてBootstrapによるモーダルの表示を打ち消しているのでしょう。ですので`UpdatePanel`のトリガーとして問題のボタンを登録する必要があります。対象の`<asp:UpdatePanel>`に

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnShowModal" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

のように指定すれば、`BtnShowModal`で`UpdatePanel2`が更新されると思います。

また`BtnShowModal`でフルポストバックが要求されるのであれば、画面の再描画時にモーダルを表示状態にしておけばよいと思います。例えば`class="modal"`を`class="modal in"`に変更するとか、`ClientScriptManager`の`RegisterStartupScript`メソッドに`$("#modal-BtnShowModal").modal("show")`を登録するといった方法があります。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。Triggersの登録で想定していた動きになりました。